# Bash-->Batch + Colon and back/forward-slash use

Tags: eclipse, bash, shell, batch-file, pydev

I'm trying to make portable pyDev automatically set up the python interpreter by using a batch script that's run before eclipse launches. I came across the following bash-script for doing just that, but I'm unable to translate it to batch (which I'm familiar with):

```
PYTHONPATH=/my/extra/python/modules python /my/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_*/PySrc/interpreterInfo.py 2>/dev/null | sed 's/INS_PATH$//g;s/OUT_PATH$//g;s/^EXECUTABLE:/Executable\\:/g' | tr -d '\n' | cat <(echo -en 'eclipse.preferences.version=1\nINTERPRETER_PATH_NEW=Name\:python\:EndName\:') - <(echo '&&&&&') >/my/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.python.pydev.prefs
```

**I tried breaking it down to see what's being replaced/piped where, but it doesn't make sense:**

```
PYTHONPATH= App/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_*/PySrc/interpreterInfo.py 2> /dev/null 
|sed '  s/ INS_PATH$/ / g; REM Delete all instances of INS_PATH that are at the end of a line
        s/ OUT_PATH$/ / g; REM Delete all instances of OUT_PATH that are at the end of a line
        s/ ^EXECUTABLE:/ Executable\\:/ g REM Replace all instances of "\nEXECUTABLE:" that are at the beginning of a line with "Executable\:"
' 
|tr -d '\n' 
|cat <(echo -en 'eclipse.preferences.version= 1 \n INTERPRETER_PATH_NEW= Name\:python\:EndName\:') - <(echo '&&&&&') 
>/my/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.python.pydev.prefs
```

---

One of the most confusing parts is the the strange use of colons and use of **'/'** vs **'\'**. 
Looking in config files I see `osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.0.v20120529-1548.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to format the "original" to make it more readable. I'll try to explain what's happening from there:

```
PYTHONPATH=/my/extra/python/modules \
    python /my/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_*/PySrc/interpreterInfo.py 2>/dev/null |
    sed '
        s/INS_PATH$//g;
        s/OUT_PATH$//g;
        s/^EXECUTABLE:/Executable\\:/g
    ' |
    tr -d '\n' |
    cat \
        <(
            echo -en 'eclipse.preferences.version=1\nINTERPRETER_PATH_NEW=Name\:python\:EndName\:'
        ) \
        - \
        <(echo '&&&&&') \
     >/my/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.python.pydev.prefs
```

Now, let's look at this section-by-section to make sense of it. I'm going to go over everything, including those parts which I expect you already know about, for the sake of completeness.

```
PYTHONPATH=/my/extra/python/modules \
```

This is setting the variable `PYTHONPATH`, which, from context, I expect tells python where to look for modules. Because we're specifying it within the same "line" as a command, two things happen:

1. The variable is automatically exported to the environment
2. The variable is only set for the individual command which is being run (ie: just the "first" command, not the whole pipeline, and it won't be in the shell's environment for use by later commands)

Next, the main command:

```
 python /my/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_*/PySrc/interpreterInfo.py 2>/dev/null |
```

Here the "python" interpreter is run, and passed the `interpreterInfo.py` script to execute.

The `_*` means that we're not specifying the specific version of `org.python.pydev` which we want (it is assumed that only a single version will be found, and that all versions will behave similarly).

The `2>/dev/null` means that any output on stderr, where errors and debug info is normally piped, will be ignored (piped to nowhere).

Now the meat of it:

```
sed '
    s/INS_PATH$//g;
    s/OUT_PATH$//g;
    s/^EXECUTABLE:/Executable\\:/g
' |
```

This does three things. The first two are similar: `INS_PATH` and `OUT_PATH` are removed from the ends of lines. Next, and the first part which you were asking about, `:` characters are replaced with `\:`. Why the double `\\` if `\:` is the goal? Mostly this is due to pedantry. Though `\:` is not a valid escape sequence, and so most `sed`s will interpret it as a literal `\` marks the beginning of an [Escape Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence), so the canonical way of specifying that you want `sed` to output a literal `\` is to specify it as `\\`. Hence, for the sequence `\:`, it is specified as `\\:`.

The `/g` at the end of each of these substitution commands means "replace globally", ie: every time the match is found, not just the first time.

The next line is straightforward:

```
tr -d '\n' |
```

This removes all newlines in the output. If I understand correctly, this results in a `\:` separated list of paths, on a single line.

Back to parts which may require explanation:

```
cat \
    <(
        echo -en 'eclipse.preferences.version=1\nINTERPRETER_PATH_NEW=Name\:python\:EndName\:'
    ) \
    - \
    <(echo '&&&&&') \
 >/my/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.python.pydev.prefs
```

That's a lot to go through all at once. Let's summarise:

```
cat input-one input-two input-n > output
```

`cat` combines ("concatenates") multiple inputs into a single output. This is actually the intended use of the `cat` command, though you may see it much more often used to output a *single* input, eg: `cat input-one`.

```
<( some-command )
```

Runs `some-command` and redirects its output into a [File Descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), whose path (`/dev/fd/N`) is passed used as an argument in the context which `<( ... )` was originally in. For example: `cat <( echo foo )` would run a command similar to `cat /dev/fd/64`, and `echo foo`, redirecting the output of `echo foo` to file descriptor `64`, for reading by `cat`. The output is `foo`, just as it would be if you ran `echo` directly.

Now, combine these two things:

```
cat <( some-command ) some-input <( some-other-command )
```

This will combine the output of `some-command`, the content of `some-input`, and the output of `some-other-command`, into a single stream. In the script you're working with, these are all being combined into a single output file.

So what about the content that is actually being build for this output? Let's look at that line-by-line as well:

```
<(
    echo -en 'eclipse.preferences.version=1\nINTERPRETER_PATH_NEW=Name\:python\:EndName\:'
)
```

This outputs the literal:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
INTERPRETER_PATH_NEW=Name\:python\:EndName\:
```

`echo -e` means "interpret backslash escape sequences", so `\n` expands into a newline. `echo -n` means "do not end output with a newline", so whatever comes next is part of the same line. In this case, that means that whatever is concatenated next will become part of the `INTERPRETER_PATH_NEW=` line.

```
-
```

A `-` is shorthand for "read from standard input", which is the default if you run `cat` by itself. Many commands use this shorthand, though for those that don't, another way of specifying this is `/dev/stdin`. It means "read in what was piped to this command", ie: the output from `tr`, which itself defaulted to reading the output from `sed`, which defaulted to reading the output from `python`.

```
<(echo '&&&&&')
```

This ends the stream with five `&` characters and a newline. I don't actually know the reason for this, so perhaps someone can comment to fill me in.

```
>/my/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.python.pydev.prefs
```

As a final step, all output is redirected (via the `>` symbol) to a file, `org.python.pydev.prefs`.

With that big overview of what is happening out of the way, it's now time to answer the pesky details which you were asking about:

**Why all the `\` characters?**

Well, in the same way that we escaped `\` within sed, we're also escaping `:` within the `.prefs` file. `\:` in the `.prefs` file seems to mean "a literal `:`" in the same way that `\\` within sed specifies a literal `\`.

**What about the `/` characters?**

`/` is the directory separater in UNIX systems (including modern Mac OSs, ie OSX). On Windows systems, `\` is used. In many languages, as noted above, `\` is also used as an escape character, so to specify a literal `\`, you may need to write it as `\\`. There is no hard rule for this. Some cross-platform languages, aware of the problem, allow `/` to be used as a directory separator on Windows as well.

I hope that clears things up. Let me know if there is anything else which requires explanation, and I'll try to edit my answer to add additional information.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting this together!